# How build and run aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C sample?

Tags: c, amazon-web-services

[Here](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C/tree/master/samples/linux/subscribe_publish_sample) is `aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C` sample. But when I invoke `make` command I got error like:

```
~/environment/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C/samples/linux/subscribe_publish_sample ((6c99912...)) $ make
make -C ../../../external_libs/mbedTLS
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ec2-user/environment/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C/external_libs/mbedTLS'
make[1]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/environment/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C/external_libs/mbedTLS'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How build and run this sample? (I am not C developer so please provide detailed answer if possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is **missing `mbedTLS` library**.

Please go to:

> /home/ec2-user/environment/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C/external_libs/mbedTLS

and have a look at it's README:

```
# Copy source code for mbedTLS into this directory
#
# You'll need to download mbedTLS from the official ARMmbed repository and
# place the files here. We recommend that you pick the latest version of 2.16
# LTS release in order to have up-to-date security fixes.
```